# IllegalArgumentException: servlets [LoginRegisterServlet] and [login.register.LoginRegisterServlet] are both mapped to url-pattern [/loginRegister]

Tags: servlets, illegalargumentexception

I have a problem with Tomcat, it stopped working. I installed Tomcat 3 weeks ago and I have made more than 50 web dynamic projects, maven projects and everythings worked great. And today Tomcat stopped working. For example I make a project in Eclipse and when I try to run it I get this message in the console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [LoginRegisterServlet] and [login.register.LoginRegisterServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/loginRegister] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:329)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2418)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1981)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1146)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4989)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
```

I can start Tomcat from Windows services, and I can open http://localhost:8080/ page in browser, but I can't start Tomcat in eclipse. Not just for one project, for all projects isn't working. The problem is with Tomcat not with all the apps. I uninstalled and installed it again and do not work. What should I do? Any feedback will be apreciated!

Comment: "SEVERE: A child container failed during start"

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [LoginRegisterServlet] and [login.register.LoginRegisterServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/loginRegister] which is not permitted" Was your "/loginRegister" code working previously?

Comment: I knoe there is only one servlet called LoginRegisterServlet and I just deleted it and now I see that Tomcat started succesfully. Thanks for reply! You helped me a lot.

Comment: I've put our comments into an answer so it more useful to people.

Answer (score 2):

From comments above

"SEVERE: A child container failed during start"

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [LoginRegisterServlet] and [login.register.LoginRegisterServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/loginRegister] which is not permitted"

Was your "/loginRegister" code working previously?

---

"I know there is only one servlet called LoginRegisterServlet and I just deleted it and now I see that Tomcat started succesfully. Thanks for reply! You helped me a lot."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error one hour ago.
I went to the server tab and i deleted the tomcat file, then i re-installed it and it worked.

Hope it might help you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that at the point when I was installing the Tomcat v9.0 in Eclipse I was adding an application to be run - I was transferring the application to the deployed ones with the arrow on the relevant window in the "Add a new Server" wizard. The application that I wanted to add happened to have errors and caused Tomcat not to be able to start. Once I deleted the so added Tomcat server and added it again without adding any application to run from the Wizard, Tomcat appeared and started without issues.