# Tomcat v9.0 server failed to start -- with a twist

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

First off, I did notice that there are multiple similar questions on this topic in SO. (e.g: [Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025776/tomcat-v9-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start-in-eclipse)). The `error message` and `console messages` are quite similar. I have tried the suggestions from that question as well as from a few others - but to no avail.

Secondly, the twist is that this works perfectly fine from a different eclipse workspace on the same laptop. The two eclipse projects are virtually identical (copy/paste). I'm hoping someone can help me figure out as to why this is so. I am more than willing to provide additional information (code, screenshots etc.) - but I don't know where to start.

A little bit of history/ context:

My web-projects suddenly started running into this problem (not sure what I changed) and after being unable to resolve it, I un-installed and re-installed eclipse as well as tomcat on my laptop. I also started with a fresh eclipse work-space. The projects in the new work-space work fine. Those in the earlier work space still show the same error.
It would indeed be very helpful to understand as to what is causing this.

update: I'm adding the error message and the console logs as indicated @Tim Biegeleison in the comment below.
Error message:
[image: Tomcat v9.0 at localhost failed to start]

Console logs:

```
Dec 13, 2020 7:50:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.MultiThrowable: 5 wrapped Throwables: [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@62727399]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@130dca52]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2654635]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2371aaca]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5b529706]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:920)
    ... 21 more

Dec 13, 2020 7:50:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 13, 2020 7:50:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Dec 13, 2020 7:50:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/lib/catalina.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: You absolutely should include the error message/stack trace so that other SO users familiar might be able to help you.

Comment: What exact Tomcat version are you running? My guess is that Eclipse is using different JVMs for each workspace -- one of which doesn't have those field-access checks enabled (or is maybe a completely different version of Java).